# Помогите пожалуйста настроить запрос с помощью Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, rxjava, retrofit2

есть ссылка на апи которую разбил на части и пытаюсь получить оттуда данные - но ничего не получается, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно написать запрос. 
Ссылка: `https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/exchange_rates?json&date=31.08.2018`

Как к ней подключаюсь:

```
public interface IMyApi_P24 {
    @GET("p24api/exchange_rates")
    Observable<P24> getCurses(@Query("json&date") String date);
}


public class RetrofitClient {
     private static Retrofit ourInstance;

   public static Retrofit getInstance() {
    if(ourInstance == null){
        ourInstance = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.privatbank.ua/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return ourInstance;
  }

    private RetrofitClient() {}
}
```

И вот мейн активити

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView rvCurs;
IMyApi_P24 iMyApi_p24;
CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
}

private void init(){
    rvCurs = findViewById(R.id.rvContainerCurs);
    rvCurs.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
    iMyApi_p24 = retrofit.create(IMyApi_P24.class);
    loadData();
}

private void loadData() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat mdformat = new 
    SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    String currDate = mdformat.format(calendar.getTime());

    compositeDisposable.add(iMyApi_p24.getCurses(currDate)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<P24>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(P24 p24) throws Exception {
                    displayData(p24);
                }
            }));
}

private void displayData(P24 p24) {
    rvCurs.setAdapter(new P24_Recycler_Adapter(p24, this));
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    compositeDisposable.clear();
    super.onStop();
}
}
```

Приложение падает, конкретной ошибки не пишет в какой строчке, только что Exception не инициализирован (но я думаю что я скорее неправильно запрос написал)
Спасибо огромное заранее!

Comment: Первое, что бросается в глаза, `json&date` это не имя параметра. Это два параметра: `json` и `date`.

Comment: Этот запрос выдает то же самое: https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/exchange_rates?date=31.08.2018&json=

Comment: Тоесть можно сделать вот так? Observable<P24> getCurses(@Query("date") String date, @Query("json") String jsonStr);

Answer (score 1):

Правильный запрос

```
public interface IMyApi_P24 {
    @GET("p24api/exchange_rates")
    Observable<P24> getCurses(@Query("date") String date, @Query("json") String str);
}
```